# Laravel API resource (Problem with creating exact API)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to create an API in the below format. But I am unable to do it. I am using the API resource. I have tried using different queries but I am not getting the exact solution.Please help me.

Thank you

what I have tried

```
$marks = StudentMarksResource::collection(StudentsMark::whereIn('academic_id',$ids)->whereIn('student_id',$studentid)->get());
```

my API resource file

```
public function toArray($request)
{


    return [

        'exam_type' => $this->exam_type,
        'details' => [
                /*  'class_id' => Course::find($this->class_id),
            'batch_id' => Batch::find($this->batch_id),
            'student_id' => Student::find($this->student_id), */
            'subject' => $this->subject,
            'marks' => $this->marks,
            'marksgrade' => $this->marksgrade,
            'total' => $this->total,
            'grade' => $this->grade,
            'percentage' => $this->percentage,
            'year' => $this->year,
        ],

    ];
}
```

what I want is this

```
   data": [

    {
        "exam_type": "Unit Test 1",
        "details": {
            //subject1 details
        },
        {
            //subject2 details
        },
        {
            //subject3 details
        },

       "exam_type": "Unit Test 2",
        "details": {
            //subject1 details
        },
        {
            //subject2 details
        },
        {
            //subject3 details
        },
    },
```

what I am getting for the above code

```
"data": [
    {
        "exam_type": "Unit Test 1",
        "details": {
            //subject1 marks details
        }
    },
    {
        "exam_type": "Unit Test 1",
        "details": {
            //subject2 marks details
         }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you can try:

1. First get exam types

```
$exam_types = StudentsMark::select('exam_type', 'student_id', 'academic_id')->whereIn('academic_id',$ids)->whereIn('student_id',$studentid)->get();

$marks = StudentMarksResource::collection($exam_types);
```

2. Now inside resource that's when you can retrieve the details

```
#do not forget to import StudentsMark
#and you can make a resource for details, just to make clean code

    return [

        'exam_type' => $this->exam_type,

        'details' => StudentsMark::where('academic_id', $this->academic_id)
                                 ->where('student_id', $this->student_id)
                                 ->get();
    ];
```

Comment: thanks for replying I am getting exact format but data is repeating

Comment: How about adding `->where('exam_type', $this->exam_type)` in the resource.

Comment: bro thank you very very very much. you don't believe me for this I was suffering from the last 2 days. thank you bro once again